# Redefining security for a browser view in Plone 4

Tags: plone, zope

I'd like to redefine security for the stock folder_contents browser View so that only members with the Reviewer role have access to it.

The class is defined in plone.app.content.browser.foldercontents.FolderContentsView

In my custom.policy product, I have

browser/configure.zcml:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    i18n_domain="custom.policy">

  <browser:page
    for="*"
    class=".overrides.FolderContentsView"
    name="folder_contents"
    template="folder_contents.pt"
    permission="cmf.ReviewPortalContent" 
    />

</configure>
```

in browser/overrides.py

```
from plone.app.content.browser.foldercontents import FolderContentsView

class ProtectedFolderContentsView(FolderContentsView):
    """ Customized FolderContentsView """
```

However, when I start the instance, I get:

```
zope.configuration.config.ConfigurationConflictError: Conflicting configuration actions
For: ('view', None, u'folder_contents', <InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IBrowserRequest>, <InterfaceClass zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IDefaultBrowserLayer>)
File "src/custom.policy/custom/policy/browser/configure.zcml", line 30.2-36.6
    <browser:page
      for="*"
      class=".overrides.FolderContentsView"
      name="folder_contents"
      template="folder_contents.pt"
      permission="cmf.ReviewPortalContent"
      />
File "eggs/plone.app.content-2.0.7-py2.6.egg/plone/app/content/browser/configure.zcml", line 15.4-20.46
      <browser:page
          for="*"
          class=".foldercontents.FolderContentsView"
          name="folder_contents"
          template="folder_contents.pt"
          permission="cmf.ListFolderContents" />
```

How can I accomplish this override with running into conflicts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this really is just custom site configuration and *not* something you'll ever build on top of, then that's exactly what overrides.zcml is for.  Create an custom/policy/overrides.zcml:

```
<configure xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope">
  <include package=".browser" file="overrides.zcml" />
</configure>
```

Then rename your browser/configure.zcml to browser/overrides.zcml.

Comment: When defined in this way, it works! What the heck? Is there something magic about using overrides.zcml instead of configure.zcml for these kinds of overrides?

Comment: Wow, I really can't find any docs for overrides.zcml, that's really bad.  At any rate, ZCML normally keeps track of what actions will be executed and considers it an error if they conflict.  The overrides.zcml file is a convention and the actions in those files are loaded and allowed to conflict with and take precedence over existing registrations.  It's meant as a way to customize an individual site without having to do "the right thing" and actually make the actions more specific.  Hence my caution that you could do it this way *if* you were not going to build anything on top of it.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried by specifying a custom browser layer?

Answer (score 3):

Register it for a more specific interface. Say zope.interface.Interface, or Products.Archetypes.interfaces.IBaseContent instead.

Comment: I did and get no conflict errors, but the security redefinition is not being picked up (I can access the view as an unprivileged member).

Comment: What interface did you register against? It could be that "*" uses zope.interface.Interface under the hood; no conflict but your registration may be ignored anyway.